# Google Apps Script: Salesforce API Call

Tags: api, google-apps-script, salesforce

Just finished breakfast and already hit a snag. I'm trying to call the salesforce REST api from my google sheets. I've written a working script locally in python, but converting it into JS, something went wrong:

```
function authenticateSF(){

  var url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
  var options = {
    grant_type:'password',
    client_id:'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    client_secret:'111111111111',
    username:'ITSME@smee.com',
    password:'smee'
  };

  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Here is the error response:

> Request failed for https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
>   returned code 400. Truncated server response:
>   {"error_description":"grant type not
>   supported","error":"unsupported_grant_type"} (use muteHttpExceptions
>   option to examine full response) (line 12, file "Code")

Mind you, these exact parameters work fine in my local python script (putting the key values inside quotations).

Here are the relevant docs:
[Google Script: Connecting to external API's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#connecting_to_public_apis)
[Salesforce: REST API guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=quickstart_oauth.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fquickstart_oauth.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's UrlFetchApp object automatically defaults to a GET request. To authenticate, you have to explicitly set in the options the method "post":

```js
function authenticateSF(){

  var url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
  var payload = {
    'grant_type':'password',
    'client_id':'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'client_secret':'111111111111',
    'username':'ITSME@smee.com',
    'password':'smee'
  };

  var options = {
    'method':'post',
    'payload':payload
  };

  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: For a GET request, `UrlFetchApp` will _ignore_ any `payload` in the `options`. If your API requires querystring parameters, you need to append them to the URL yourself.

Comment: That's a great catch. Isn't that one of the main differences between GET and POST requests in general? GET requests pass variables through the URL only while POST does not?

Comment: POST can pass variables through the URL, although it's "uncommon". I use the quotes because I've run into it with Google's APIs, for example [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) which has _query_ and _body_ parameters for a POST request. You can go crazy trying to fill in `payload`, wondering why your requests don't work!

Comment: Yep, that would've been me. Going crazy trying to figure out what I did wrong. That's like, 90% of my time. Thank you @mogsdad